# mostrar modal con jquery y bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

buenas noches estoy intentato llamar una modal con  bootstrap 4 y jquery pero no me sale lo hice como dice la documentacion  $('#myModal').modal('show') pero me marca un error 
https://gyazo.com/7ab3403b00139197545ecb44fa4a44b8

podrian ayudarme por favor llevo buen rato intentando y nada

```js
function editarProducto(id){
       /*$('#formularioEditar')[0].reset();
    $.ajax({
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'controller/cliente/modificarSeleccion.php',
      'data': 'id='+id,
    }).done(function(valores){
      //console.log(valores);
    //  $('#mensajee').addClass("mostrar").html('Se Agrego Correctamente El Producto').show(200).delay(2500).hide(200);
    var datos = eval(valores);
    $('#id-prod').val(id);
    $('#nombrePersona').val(datos[6]);
    $('#edadPersona').val(datos[7]);
    //$('#editarCantidad').val(datos[7]);
    $('#personaReferencia').val(datos[8]);
    $('#alias').val(datos[1]);
    //$('#editarPrecio').val(datos[5]);
    $('#edad').val(datos[2]);
    $('#fechaInicial').val(datos[3]);
    //$("#editarProducto").modal("show"); 
    /*$('#myModal').modal({
      show: true
  });
 });*/
    $('#editarProducto').modal({
            show:true,
            backdrop:'static'
          });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Jquery ui -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <header>"MVC PRUEBA"</header>
    <section>

    <div id="agregar-registros">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre del dueño</th>
      <th>edad</th>
      <th>persona Referencia</th>
      <th>Mascota Alias</th>
      <th>edad Mascota</th>
      <th>fecha de nacimiento</th>
      <th>opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <?php
        include 'controller/cliente/traerRegistros.php';
      ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>


      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">



          <div class="col">
            <form id="formularioAgregar" class="formulario">
                <table border="0" alling="center">
          <h2>datos de cliente</h2>
          <tr>
              <td><label>Ingresa el nombre de la persona</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="nombrePersona" id="nombrePersona"></td>
          </tr>
              <td><label>ingrese edad</label></td>
              <td><input type="number" name="edadPersona" id="edadPersona"></td>
          <tr>
          <tr>
              <td><label>persona de referencia</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="personaReferencia" id="personaReferencia"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><label>nombre del perro</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="alias" id="alias"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><label>edad del perro</label></td>
              <td><input type="number" name="edad" id="edad"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><label>fecha de nacimiento</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fechaInicial" id="fechaInicial"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><div id="mensaje"></div></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" name="agregar" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Datos</button>
            </form>
          </div>

  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:editarProducto('.$idPersona.');" >Editar</a>



          <!-- Modal editar-->
          <div>
              <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="formularioEditar" class="formulario">
                        <table border="0" alling="center">
                          <h2>datos de cliente</h2>
                          <tr>
                              <td><input type="text" required="required" readonly="readonly" id="id-prod" name="id-prod" readonly="readonly" style="visibility: hidden;" height: "5px;"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td><label>Ingresa el nombre de la persona</label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="nombrePersona" id="nombrePersona"></td>
                          </tr>
                              <td><label>ingrese edad</label></td>
                              <td><input type="number" name="edadPersona" id="edadPersona"></td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td><label>persona de referencia</label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="personaReferencia" id="personaReferencia"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td><label>nombre del perro</label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="alias" id="alias"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td><label>edad del perro</label></td>
                              <td><input type="number" name="edad" id="edad"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td><label>fecha de nacimiento</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fechaInicial" id="fechaInicial"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="2"><div id="mensaje"></div></td>
                          </tr>
                          </table>
                          
                      </form>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="actualizar" id="actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
            


<!-- jQuery first -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- tether -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP MIN -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery para ui -->
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- codigo del calendario en assets -->
  <script src="assets/calendario/calendario.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, en tu codigo tiene la siguiente linea

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:editarProducto('.$idPersona.');" >Editar</a>
```

Agregale el data-toggle que permitira mostrar el modal y el data-target que indica cual es el div que usaras como modal. De la siguiente manera:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:editarProducto('.$idPersona.');" >Editar</a>
```

Comment: eso lo intente hace mucho data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" y no me funcionaba , no sabia sobre esto type="button" en una etiqueta <a></a> no lo habia visto y por eso opte por lamarla por medio de javascript   cosas pequeñas te hacen sufrir bastante     muchisimas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: pero ya no le llegan los parametros a la funcion de href="javascript:editarProducto('.$idPersona.');"

Comment: jaja me ando respondiendo solo pero ya quedo muchas gracias jose liza                <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="editarProducto('.$idPersona.')">Editar</a>';

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte Carlos Enrique

Comment: Carlos Enrique, podrias darle un "respuesta util" a mi respuesta, Gracias

Comment: listo antes no podia por eso no lo puse gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si la respuesta de arriba no te funciona, prueba con colocar el request de jquery al final del body y colocarlos de tal orden que jquery quede de primero, luego bootstrap.s, y luego lo demás

Comment: siento que el error es ahi tambien ya hice lo que me dijiste si te das cuenta tengo dos enlaces a jquery jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js y jquery-3.2.1.js  uno lo utilizo para la versiond e bootstrap 4 y el otro para usar jquery ui me pide usar esa version no se si exista otra forma de tal manera de usar solo uno

Comment: bueno, deberias ordenar bien tu estructura, ademas asegurate de copiar el codijo de javascript que include la documentación de Bootstrap, en el final, puedes intentar tambien crear un propio modal, busca uno en google, hay muchos, incluso en github!